# Json Schema Child value validation

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Looking for JSON SCHEMA
I have the above json as request using json schema validation i want to make sure the value of 'ActionCode' should be same as HeaderActionCode for any level of child I can have

```
    {
        "Body": {
            "LeadDetails": {
                "HeaderActionCode": "Add",
                "ActionCode": "Add",
                "Version": 1,
                "LineItems": [
                    {
                        "ActionCode": "Add",
                        "Version": 0,
                        "LineItems": [
                            {
                                "ActionCode": "Add",
                                "Version": 0,
                                "LineItems": [
                                    {
                                        "ActionCode": "Add",
                                        "Version": 0
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the above json as request using json schema validation i want to make sure the value of 'ActionCode' should be same as HeaderActionCode for any level of child I can have

Comment: Is it always children of `LineItems`? is it possible to have nested `HeaderActionCode`?

Comment: No it is not possible in requets once i will get HeaderActionCode and i have to make sure all the childs ActionCode have same value. need json schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is using a recursion and an unusual use of throwing Error in order to break early if we find an invalid item or sub-item. This is actually DFS (Depth First Search).

```js
var obj = {Body:{LeadDetails:{HeaderActionCode:"Add",ActionCode:"Add",Version:1,LineItems:[{ActionCode:"Add",Version:0,LineItems:[{ActionCode:"Add",Version:0,LineItems:[{ActionCode:"Add",Version:0}]}]}]}}};

function inspectLineItems(arr, HeaderActionCode) {
  if (!arr) return true;
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.ActionCode != HeaderActionCode || !inspectLineItems(item.LineItems, HeaderActionCode)) {
      throw new Error("missmatch")
    }
  })
  return true;
}

function inspectLeadDetails(obj) {
  try {
    var HeaderActionCode = obj.HeaderActionCode;
    return inspectLineItems(obj.LineItems, HeaderActionCode);
  } catch (ex) {
    return false
  }
}

console.log(inspectLeadDetails(obj.Body.LeadDetails))
```

Comment: Looking for a json schema validation not code

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

We can do it via [**Breadth-first search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) iteration

```
const validate = (value) => {
  let data = value.Body.LeadDetails
  let actionCode = data.HeaderActionCode
  let items = data.LineItems
  while(items.length > 0){
     let i = items.shift()
     if(i.ActionCode !== actionCode){
       return false
     }
     if(i.LineItems){
       items.push(...i.LineItems)
     }
   }
  return true
}

console.log(validate(json))
```

```js
let json =
{
    "Body": {
        "LeadDetails": {
            "HeaderActionCode": "Add",
            "ActionCode": "Add",
            "Version": 1,
            "LineItems": [
                {
                    "ActionCode": "Add",
                    "Version": 0,
                    "LineItems": [
                        {
                            "ActionCode": "Add",
                            "Version": 0,
                            "LineItems": [
                                {
                                    "ActionCode": "Add",
                                    "Version": 0
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

const validate = (value) => {
  let data = value.Body.LeadDetails
  let actionCode = data.HeaderActionCode
  if(actionCode !== data.ActionCode){
    return false 
   }
  let items = data.LineItems
  while(items.length > 0){
     let i = items.shift()
     if(i.ActionCode !== actionCode){
       return false
     }
     if(i.LineItems){
       items.push(...i.LineItems)
     }
   }
  return true
}

console.log(validate(json))
```